# Reset Sync for all users. Is it possible?

Tags: integration, salesforce-for-outlook, outlook, sync, office-365

I am working in a project that requires Salesforce integration with Office 365 for synchronizing contacts and events between Exchange 365 and Salesforce. Currently every user (that has their account mapped with their account on Exchange Online) has to go to "Exchange Sync Status" section and reset their synchronization by themselves (see the attached image below).

[image: Exchange Sync Status]

My question is since the system can have dozens or hundreds of users in the near future and they will all be linked to their accounts on Office 365, is it possible for a system administration to reset the synchronization for all of them at the same time? If so, do I need to create a button and process it using Visualforce and Apex, and how can I call the buton "Reset Sync" from Apex? 
Thank you very much.